# Browser Console Unable to Click on Pull-Down Menu

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver-io

Which element should I select/match and programmatically click in the console to cause the pull-down menu below to appear?

[image]

```html
<div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-8 MuiGrid-grid-sm-4">
 <label class="jss2019 jss2020 jss2024" role="group" aria-labelledby="rate-per-acre-label">
 <span class="MuiFormLabel-root jss2021 jss2028">Rate/Acre</span>
 <div class="jss2027">
  <div class="jss2025 jss2014">
   <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth" data-test="rate-value-input">
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense MuiOutlinedInput-marginDense">
     <input aria-invalid="false" id="rate-per-acre-left" name="rateValue" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense" value="0">
     <fieldset aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 8px;" class="jss41 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
      <legend class="jss42" style="width: 0.01px;">
       <span>​</span>
      </legend>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jss2026">
   <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth" data-test="rate-unit-dropdown">
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense MuiOutlinedInput-marginDense">
     <div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiSelect-outlined MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="rate-per-acre-right"
 id="rate-per-acre-right"
    >BG</div>
     <input name="rateUnit" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="MuiSelect-nativeInput" value="bg">
     <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon MuiSelect-iconOutlined" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
      <path d="M7.41 8.59L12 13.17l4.59-4.58L18 10l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z">
      </path>
     </svg>
     <fieldset aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 8px;" class="jss41 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
      <legend class="jss42" style="width: 0.01px;">
       <span>​</span>
      </legend>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </label>
</div>
```

I have tried several elements. However, could not get it to click. Does the DOM need to have a button element to be able to click?

These two did not work in the console for Chrome/FF:

```
$('[id="rate-per-acre-right"]').click()
$('[data-test="rate-unit-dropdown"]').click()
```

Further investigation has shown that trying to click an SVG element using `click()` will [show errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUI71.png) because SVG elements don't have a `click` method.

**Aditional Information**

- The screen area occupied by the `label` element in the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfTVw.png
- Some HTML related to a "Crop and Maturity" dropdown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyHZC.png
- The label area of "Crop and Maturity" showing Corn as the crop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLs3E.png
- An animated gif of HTML related to the Crop and Maturity dropdown.

Comment: Too much information my friend. You will need to do some debugging (or ask the developer) to find out what commonalities exist between different dropdown label containers and event handlers that respond to clicks (or some other event) and display the drop-down menu. If there is no commonality, you will need to find out what element is listening for a mouse event for each separate drop down. Also please do not post images of code. They are quite difficult or impossible to work with, as are single lines of machine generated HTML with no line feeds.

Comment: If you need to add an event listener to the document that uses event capture to grab click events and log them to the console. Clicking on "event" icons adjacent to elements inspected in the console (in Firefox at least) should let you inspect the source code of event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the DOM need to have a button element to be able to click?

No. Any element can have an event listener added to it to listen for clicks, with caveats that responding to events can be turned off in CSS, and elements that are hidden or behind elements with a higher stacking order won't respond to mouse input.

> Which element should I select/match to click the pull-down menu

Looking at the DOM structure of the posted HTML, clicking the SVG element should work - a real click on it would travel up the DOM to whatever event listener was listening for clicks. Getting the click to work in Selenium assumes that it works in real browsers outside of testing - which was not confirmed in the post.

---

**Afterword:** In practice, you could display the page in a browser and right click the element being clicked. Choose "inspect element" to show which element it is.

---

**Updates:**

1. Actually the `svg` and `path` elements are SVG, not HTML, elements and don't have `click` methods. However:

   - The `svg` element is inside a `label` statement, and clicking it dispatches a new event, with an updated target value, to the element the `label` tag applies to (which in the posted code is the element selected by `input#rate-per-acre-left`).

   Simulating a click on the label element also dispatches a new click event to the labelled element.

   While you may be able to trigger a click event on the svg element in jQuery, simulating a click on the label element should be equivalent to clicking *anywhere within the label tag's content*:

   ```
      $('[aria-labelledby="rate-per-acre-label"]').click()
   ```
2. It may be necessary to check

   - What element the menu handler is listening on.
   - what event type the handler is listening for. `HTMLElement.click()` does **not** fire preceding `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on the element.
   - What `event` properties the handler validates before proceeding,  e.g. does it require a particular value of `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`to proceed?

   ( A code snippet to demonstrate events produced by `click()`:

```js
"use strict";
div.addEventListener("mousedown", event=>console.log(event.type));
div.addEventListener("mouseover", event=>console.log(event.type));
div.addEventListener("mouseup", event=>console.log(event.type));
div.addEventListener("mouseout", event=>console.log(event.type));
div.addEventListener("click", event=>console.log(event.type));

setTimeout(()=>div.click(), 3000)
```

```html
<div id="div">Click me and/or wait for <code>.click</code> method to be called</div>
```

)

Comment: $('[data-test="rate-unit-dropdown"] svg').click() threw an error

Comment: $('[aria-labelledby="rate-per-acre-label"]').click() did not work. It is not selecting the pull-down menu. See picture.

Comment: @traltor I am trying to open the pull-down menu by using the selector in the Chrome/FF console before I can use I use it in the test automation script. I expect the pull-down to open/close when I run that selector in the console.

Comment: Can you open the open the pull-down menu by clicking the page shown in the browser? If so, what is the `target` element of the click - and see answer about getting extra debugging information.